# I want to make a function to sum numbers and if the numbers have 10 exclude it and if the numbers have 5 subtract it

Tags: python

```
def addition(*num):
    for no in num :
        if no == 10 :
            continue
            return sum(num)
        elif no == 5 :
            return (sum(num) - no)
        else :
            return sum(num)
        
print (addition(10,5,10,15,25))  
print (addition(10, 20, 30, 10, 15, 5, 100))
```

I want to make a function to sum numbers and if the numbers have 10 exclude it and if the numbers have 5 subtract it

Comment: You already made the function, what is your question about it?

Comment: Because you `return` in every branch of the `if`, your loop will only iterate once (except in the case of `10` because of the `continue`). Looks like you want to keep a running total and add/subtract to that. Then return it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what your question is but I think you're looking for something like this:

```
def addition(*num):
    count_10 = num.count(10)
    count_5 = num.count(5)

    return sum(num) - 10*count_10 - 10*count_5
```

Tests:

> addition(10,5,10,15,25) returns 35

> addition(10, 20, 30, 10, 15, 5, 100) returns 160

Comment: Your code will iterate over the list 3 times. While not really a problem for small lists, a single iteration solution might be preferred.

Comment: That is true, but I think OP is a beginner and personally I think this is a clean way to do it. Although I do get that this may not be preferred.

Comment: @001, Low level C code will always be faster than iterations in Python code so this method is likely to be faster than any Python loop or comprehension that implement the conditions with if/else constructs even if it does go through the list thrice.

Answer (score 1):

here is your fixed code:

```
def addition(*num):
    result = 0
    for no in num :
        # exclude 10s
        if no == 10 :
            continue
        # subract 5s
        elif no == 5 :
            result-= no
        # add others 
        else :
            result += no
    return result
        
print (addition(10,5,10,15,25))  
print (addition(10, 20, 30, 10, 15, 5, 100))
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I've been trying to do. This was helpful.

Comment: Your answer is correct, though, you can simplify the condition, like `if no == 5` then `elif no != 10`, there wouldn't be a need for the `else` case then.

Comment: I just tried to show "AhmedEl-Bialy" his fixed code. So I did not try to improve it @Zero FYI.  
For the "sum" shadowing builtin function I fixed it as suggested by "001"

Comment: Yeah mate, as I said, your answer is correct, no worries though.

Comment: I fixed it in my code too, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put `return` at every place in the loop, it will cause your loop run exactly once (except when the iterator is 10 you will gain one more iteration for each 10, your code will do nothing in this case), `return` stops the execution of the code and returns the value you wanted.

You will want to loop through the iterable, but with faulty early return you aren't looping through it.

That said you can achieve what you wanted in one-line:

```
def add(*nums): return sum((i if i != 5 else -5) for i in nums if i != 10)
```

Test:

```
add(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
#35
nums = [62, 96, 95, 29, 15, 9, 99, 8, 26, 12, 0, 53, 24, 45, 59, 11, 63, 19, 39, 46, 93, 22, 2, 28, 38, 28, 71, 1, 61, 89, 32, 2]

add(*nums)
#1277
```